# Anyone advise about SQL queries and grouping 15 min interval data in to days?

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm hoping someone can answer this question about an SQL query I'm tyring to write, it's probably fairly basic but it's driving me nuts.

I have a table which contains data which is written every 15 minutes for some agents logged in to a telephone system.  Here's a sample of some of the fields setup, there's more but I'm keeping things simple and quick to type

```
FieldName          Size  Type
BeginTimePeriodDt  93    datetime
User_Id            12    varchar
EndTimePeriodDt    93    datetime
TotalLoginTime      4    int
```

And a sample of what the data is.  There's a lot more agents but I've kept it simple again.

```
BeginTimePeriodDT    User_ID EndTimePeriodDt      TotalLoginTime
2012-09-10 13:30:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-10 13:45:00  35
2012-09-10 13:30:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-10 13:45:00  900
2012-09-10 13:45:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-10 14:00:00  900
2012-09-10 13:45:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-10 14:00:00  600
2012-09-10 14:00:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-10 14:15:00  250
2012-09-10 14:00:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-10 14:15:00  95
2012-09-11 13:30:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-11 13:45:00  35
2012-09-11 13:30:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-11 13:45:00  900
2012-09-11 13:45:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-11 14:00:00  900
2012-09-11 13:45:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-11 14:00:00  600
2012-09-11 14:00:00  XXXXXX  2012-09-11 14:15:00  250
2012-09-11 14:00:00  YYYYYY  2012-09-11 14:15:00  95
```

As you can see every agent logged in gets a record written every 15 minutes.  What I'm trying to do is takes those records and add up the log in time.  Now if the table only contained 1 days records per agent then it would be a very easy thing to do, but...

the table contains records for multiple days 15 minute intervals per agent :-(

The bit I'm having the trouble with is figuring out how to group and add an agents intervals per day up and return a daily total.

So I want to end up with something like

```
2012-09-10 XXXXXX 1185
2012-09-11 XXXXXX 1185
2012-09-10 YYYYYY 2000
2012-09-11 YYYYYY 1300
```

(I know my maths don't add up to the data above, I  can't be arsed working the sums out :-P)

I'd be much appreciated if someone could come up with an answer for me.

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgre? You have not tried at least one query? If yes, please post it too so there is something to start with

Comment: RDBMS? Try to reduce the question size. Your query or scenario does not seem as much complex as presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
       MONTH(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
       DAY(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
       User_ID, 
       SUM(TotalLoginTime)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
         MONTH(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
         DAY(BeginTimePeriodDT), 
         User_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do It

```
SELECT dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, beginTimePeriodDt)), UserId, SUM(TotalLoginTime)
FROM test 
group by dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, beginTimePeriodDt)), userId
order by 1, 2
```